# PHP: Force redirect page

Tags: php, ajax

I have page which is calling through JQuery ajax. I do update in page ***experience.php***. Hence, update part is working fine.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST["update"]) ) {

        $status = false;
        $status = $experience->update($_POST);

        if($status) {
                $idh = md5($_SESSION["mainid"].$_SESSION["tsa_gong"]);
                header("Location: particular_one.php?idh=$idh&ajax_show=experience");
       } else {
             echo '<p style="color: #fff;">Error: cannot update</p>';
       }
}
```

But PHP header function is not working fine. It has following error. And it hangs in there which looks ugly for user.

> [WARNING] Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..

I want to ignore warning or error I get. I want PHP to forcefully redirect to page I intended. Is there any ways to achieve that?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be sending output, unless you have a space or something prior to the opening PHP tag. The error you're seeing is caused by output being sent to the browser. Headers have to go first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use inline JavaScript

<strike>header("Location: particular_one.php?idh=$idh&ajax_show=experience");</strike>

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'particular_one.php?idh={$idh}&ajax_show=experience';</script>";
```

Comment: This is it! Appreciate that sir.